# add multiple items to row using vectorized pandas function, not iterrows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather large bioinformatics dataset that I'm processing using pandas. It looks something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['a=1|b=4', 'a=2|b=3', 'a=1|b=1'], 
     [None]*3, [None]*3], index=['metadata', 'a', 'b']).T
>>> df
  metadata     a     b
0  a=1|b=4  None  None
1  a=2|b=3  None  None
2  a=1|b=1  None  None
```

I want to extract the metadata from the 'metadata' column and put it in the a and b columns (yes, bioinformatics file formats are terrible). The way I'm currently doing this is using df.iterrows():

```
>>> def make_dict(string):
        return dict([kv.split('=') for kv in string.split('|')])

>>> for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        for k, v in make_dict(row['metadata']).iteritems():
            df[k][idx] = v

>>> df
  metadata  a  b
0  a=1|b=4  1  4
1  a=2|b=3  2  3
2  a=1|b=1  1  1
```

This works, but is *extremely slow* for large datasets. My question is: is there a way to get the same result without using iterrows, using vectorized pandas functions, and get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be faster

```
In [124]: regex = r'\w=(\d+)\|\w=(\d+)'

In [127]: df[['a', 'b']] = df.metadata.str.extract(regex)

In [128]: df
Out[128]: 
  metadata  a  b
0  a=1|b=4  1  4
1  a=2|b=3  2  3
2  a=1|b=1  1  1

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

EDIT:

Interesting, looks like it's actually slower, but I suspect that this will scale well

```
In [131]: %%timeit
   .....: df[['a', 'b']] = df.metadata.str.extract(regex)
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 973 µs per loop

In [135]: %%timeit
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        for k, v in make_dict(row['metadata']).items():
            df[k][idx] = v
   .....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 440 µs per loop
```

Comment: One issue with this is it's sensitive to ordering (throwing away some info) e.g. `b=1|a=2`.

Comment: Yeah, the ordering is actually an issue, and furthermore there are mixed datatypes so I'd need to be a bit clever coming up with the regex, but I think preprocessing the data should do the trick. I'll check how it scales on my dataset. Thanks!

Comment: ohh, that's true Andy. Could mix in some name groups and extract the name as well: `regex = r'(?P<G1>\w)=(?P<V1>\d+)\|(?P<G2>\w)=(?P<V2>\d+)'`... then some clever reshaping.

Comment: Aftermath: I ended up being a coward and preprocessing the data before importing into pandas. But I'm still curious if there's a general solution, using something like apply or map.